# Default X509TrustManager and wildcard hostname validation?

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, x509

I am constructing a default X509TrustManager that's gonna be used for hostname validations:

```
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = null;
    try {
        trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();

        for (int i = 0; i < trustManagers.length; i++) {
            TrustManager t = trustManagers[i];
            if (t instanceof X509TrustManager) {
                this.defaultTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) t;
                return;
            }
        }
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException e) {
        throw new CelleryCellSTSException("Error while setting trust manager", e);
    }
```

However, I can't find out anywhere if this is gonna support wildcard certificates as well or do I need to build a custom trust manager just for that ? Is there any documentation somewhere available on this, I would like to read more how wildcard validation really works if it supported ? I'm using java 8 and 11, thanks.

Comment: FWIW the rules to apply to check names are in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-7 with updates in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8399#section-2.3 with everything detailed and summarized in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125 which is well required reading, with specific text for wildcards (§6.4.3)

Answer (score 0):

In Java 7 up the TrustManager's created by TrustManagerFactory do hostname checking if (and only if) an 'endpoint identification' algorithm is set for the particular *connection* being made (more exactly, the `SSLSocket` or `SSLEngine`), see [here for socket](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-11+28/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/X509TrustManagerImpl.java#L230) and [here for engine](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/jdk-11+28/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/X509TrustManagerImpl.java#L288). The [supported algorithms HTTPS and LDAPS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/X509ExtendedTrustManager.html) are actually implemented [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/util/HostnameChecker.java) (with HTTPS internally called TLS) which you can see handles valid wildcards (only in DNS name, not IP address) but rejects invalid ones.

HttpsURLConnection and 11-up java.net.http.HttpClient use the 'HTTPS' algorithm. For other ways of invoking JSSE, either your code or the relevant middleware must set endpoint-id if you want it done.